# VBA Array Formula and Goal Seek in IF Then Statement

Tags: excel, vba

This code doesnt run. It first looks into a range, if 0 does not exist then select least negative value, by using array formula. Then goal seek to set selected cell to 0 by changing value of a cell on same row, left 4 columns. If 0 exists do nothing. Any help appreciated

```
Sub Test()
    Dim Cel As Integer
        For Each Cel In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("V17:V57")
            If Cel.Value <> 0 Then
            Cel.Find(Application.WorksheetFunction.FormulaArray(MAX(IF(V17:V57<=0,V17:V57),MIN(V17:V57))))
            Cel.Select
            Cel.GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Cel.Offset(0, -4)
            End If
    Next Cel
End Sub
```

Looks like the previous comments/responses were deleted. Here's the latest version of the code, modified as per previous responses. Still doesn't run. I removed `.Activate` at the end of `Cel.Find`. Now there's a compile Syntax error. Any help apprciated

```
Sub Test()
Dim Cel As Range
    For Each Cel In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("V17:V57").Cells
        If Cel.Value <> 0 Then

        Cel.Find(What:="MAX(IF(V17:V57<=0,V17:V57),MIN(V17:V57))", After:= _
        ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        Cel.GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Cel.Offset(0, -4)
        End If
    Next Cel
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm still stuck on this. Am trying for eg to understand if the parameteres in the Find statement are set correctly. Eg I change the `After:=` from `ActiveCell` to the last cell in the range I'm working with. ie to `Cells(57, 22)`. Still no luck. The following line of code from above macro gives me a compile error. `Cel.Find(What:="MAX(IF(V17:V57<=0,V17:V57),MIN(V17:V57))", After:=Cells(57, 22), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)`

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the parentheses in your Find method.

Use:

```
Cel.Find What:="MAX(IF(V17:V57<=0,V17:V57),MIN(V17:V57))", After:= _
ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False
```

Instead of:

```
Cel.Find(What:="MAX(IF(V17:V57<=0,V17:V57),MIN(V17:V57))", After:= _
ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

Comment: I tried it but am now getting a run time error 13 type mismatch